# Apache Camel - How to configure the data port range for FTP Client Active mode

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

In Apache Camel, how to configure the data port range for FTP Client Active mode?

I am going to set up a FTP client and have to limit the port range for active mode due to existence of firewall. However, I cannot see an option in the list of FTP module mention the port range setting.

http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any. You can manipulate the ftpClient options through the URI, e.g.

```
from("ftp://foo@myserver?password=secret&ftpClient.dataTimeout=30000").to("bean:foo");
```

However, `FTPClient` doesn't have proper setter methods for the active port range - it only has the `setActivePortRange` method which accepts two integer parameters.

You will have to configure your own `FtpClient` and use it in the route by leveraging the `ftpClient` parameter:

```
from("ftp://foo@myserver?password=secret&ftpClient=#myFtpClient").to("bean:foo");
```

Comment: We should make this easier. I have logged a ticket to add support for activePortRange option: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10246